# How to transfer .frm files to table?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have .frm files from Windows and now I use Ubuntu. How can I create the same table as in Windows from only .frm files? I read that I can just copy paste those files, but in Ubuntu, there is no MySQL/data folder and I have no idea where they store MySQL tables with .frm type files. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `.frm` file just contains the table format, and is **not** the entire table.  You need the data file as well, which is probably `.myd`/`.myi`.

Once you do move those files over, be sure to run [`mysql_upgrade`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html) to ensure that those files you copied will be 100% compatible with the specific version of MySQL you are running.

Comment: where to find those .myd/.myi?

Comment: @hey, same place you found your .frm.  If you don't see a .myd/.myi, then you probably aren't using MyISAM.  Then, it depends on the storage engine you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Wait a minute !!

Please keep in mind that .frm files contains table description layout only.

If you have all MyISAM tables, then copying the corresponding .MYD and .MYI files to the same folder location as the .frm is sufficient. @Brad already stated this in his answer. (+1 from me on his answer)

Now, if the table is InnoDB, moving .frm will not be sufficient. Why?

InnoDB stores four types of info in /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1

- Data Pages
- Index Pages
- Table MetaData
- MVCC Data

The ibdata1 file must be copied as is to /var/lib/mysql. You must also make sure all setting for innodb in the source DB server's /etc/my.cnf are copied into the /etc/my.cnf of the target DB server.

If any portion of your data is InnoDB, you are much better off performing a mysqldump of all data (except the information_schema and mysql databases) and loading it into a fresh install of MySQL on the target machine.

What about the mysql database? There are two ways to port the mysql schema without using mysql_upgrade:

OPTION 1 : Use [**mk-show-grants**](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-show-grants.html) (or Percona Toolkit's pt-show-grants)

This dumps out all the MySQL Grants as SQL statements, which is completely portable to any MySQL 5.x instance.

OPTION 2 : Run these commands (My personal emulation of what mk-show-grants does)

```
mysql -hhostaddr -umyuserid -pmypassword --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -hhostaddr -umyuserid -pmypassword --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

The output from either of these methods will result in the GRANT commands for all non-anonymous users (which is version independent). Once the MySQLUserGrants.sql file is made, load that into the target DB server.

Comment: Good answer!  +1 from me as well.